# Will gradient accumulate with multiple loss in RNNs?

Tags: python, optimization, deep-learning, gradient, recurrent-neural-network

Suppose I'm using pytorch for implementation. Say I have a RNN like model, which have a loss at every step:

```
for step in step_cnts:
    output = rnn(input, hidden)
    loss = loss + criteria(output, target)
```

When backward with `loss.backward()`, will gradient accumulate at every step of the RNN? 
And won't this accumulating leads to gradient explode?

By the way, if I average the loss with `loss = loss / step_cnts`, will the gradient be different from 
the sum version?